# Can't push the docker image to gcp-cluster

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, tensorflow-serving

So I did a tutorial based on tensorflow-servings and Kubernetes. All steps are working fine except the docker image pushing to the cluster.

this is the tutorial that i have tried.
https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/serving/serving_kubernetes

And when I'm trying to push the docker image it gives an error like this,

[image]

I have tried to create the cluster with scopes also. But the result is same as above.

The command I use to create a cluster with scopes:

`gcloud container clusters create resnet-serving-cluster --num-nodes 5 --scopes=storage-rw`

So what is the wrong with this? Have I done something wrong???

Comment: Have you tried what the WARNING is suggesting?

Comment: yes. It's nothing much but about configuring gcloud docker in gcp

Comment: The warning specifies that after running that command you don't have to use `gcloud docker` to push images, you do it with docker directly.

Comment: yes I tried it also. But the result is same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok found the answer. My project ID and registry name are not equal. I re-tag the docker image with new registry name providing my project id and push it. It works.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a variety of reasons.

1) I'd recommend to start with check if full API access has been granted. 
[image]

2) Update gcloud components `gcloud components update`

3) Use gsutil to make sure you have permission to write to the bucket:

```
$ gsutil acl get gs://<my-bucket>
```

Comment: all looks fine, But nothing has changes. the result is same

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to **push** your image into your private registry on **gcloud**. Please verify if you can access your private registry:

```
gcloud container images list-tags gcr.io/"your-project"/"image"
```

all information about **gcloud private registry** you can find [here:](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/quickstart)

Additional helpful information you can find [here](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/overview)
Please notice that:

> By default, **project Owners and Editors** have push and pull permissions
>   for that project's Container Registry bucket.
>   Project Viewers have pull permission only.

Comment: this gives some digest, tags and timestamp details

Comment: Please Verify your credentials (as mentioned by  Esteban Garcia) you can push your image using docker into your private registry.
What is the output of __gcloud beta auth configure-docker__?

Comment: this is the output "gcloud credential helpers already registered correctly." And when I used docker push instead of gcloud docker -- push, the same thing was happend.

Comment: What is your "docker version" ?

Comment: Docker version 18.09.4, build d14af54

Comment: Could you please verify your permissions? Helpful information you can find in the second link.

Comment: I'm the project owner. So by default I have push and pull permissions. So why this?

Comment: I think I should try with a different google account...XD